# How to create a new node under the current node that wraps the current node's text?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Say I have an HTML file like this:

```html
<ol>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
</ol>

<ul>
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
<li> </li>
</ul>
```

For those list items, whether it being in an ordered or unordered list, I want to wrap the text of that <li> element in a <p> tag. So that the processed HTML file would look like this:

```html
<ol>
<li><p>item 1</p></li>
<li><p>item 2</p></li>
</ol>

<ul>
<li><p>item 3</p></li>
<li><p>item 4</p></li>
<li> </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the *.xsl* file I have written:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    

    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='*' />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='*'>
        <xsl:copy-of select='.' />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='li'>
        <xsl:if test='normalize-space(.)'>
            <xsl:element name='p'>
                 <xsl:value-of select='.' />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this does not work. Can anyone tell me where I did wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a template matching `li`, but it is never applied because the template processing its parent element copies all its content *as is*. Also, your 1st template is redundant; the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#built-in-rule) will do that for you.

Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:template match='*'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='li[normalize-space()]'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select='.' />
            </p>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, you provided an insightful hint! I tweaked your code as follows in my own answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @michael.hor257k. I have solved this problem.
The code that works is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    

    <xsl:template match='*'>
        <xsl:copy select='.'>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='*'/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='li[normalize-space()]'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select='.' />
            </p>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't see that your "tweak" adds anything except producing an error on a more strict processor. The `select` attribute is not allowed on `xsl:copy` element. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9ek